# std::bad_alloc exception thrown when operator= method is called C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, bad-alloc

I'm writing my very first class in C++, which is a polynomial, and I've come across a bad_alloc exception thrown when I perform

```
P=Q; //(P,Q being polynomials)
```

I suppose the fact that bad_alloc is thrown (and sometimes the process terminates with -1073741819 status) has little to do with the fact that the memory is full but more with the fact that is something fundamentally wrong abut the way I constructed my class (and it's my first time working with dynamic memory too).
Any help is much appreciated.

```
class  Polinom
{
    int grad;
    int * coef;
public:
    Polinom(){ coef=new int; coef[0]=0; grad=0;}
    Polinom(int x, int *c);
    Polinom(int x) {coef=new int[x];}
    Polinom(const Polinom &);
    ~Polinom(){ delete[] coef; }
    Polinom operator=(Polinom);
};

Polinom::Polinom(int x, int * c)
{
    int i;
    coef=new int[x];
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        coef[i]=c[i];
    }
}

Polinom::Polinom(const Polinom &Q)
{
    int i;
    grad=Q.grad;
    coef=new int[grad];
    for(i=0;i<grad;i++)
    {
        coef[i]=Q.coef[i];
    }
}

Polinom Polinom::operator=(Polinom Q)
{
    int i;
    delete[] coef;
    grad=Q.grad;
    coef=new int[grad];
    for(i=0;i<grad;i++)
        coef[i]=Q.coef[i];

    cout<<"finally";
    return (*this);
}

int main()
{
    int *v,*w;
    int i,n;

    cin>>n;
    v=new int[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){ cin>>v[i]; }
    Polinom P(n,v);
    delete[] v;

    cin>>n;
    w=new int[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){ cin>>w[i]; }
    Polinom Q(n,w);
    delete[] w;

    P=Q;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you use vectors your problems will probably disappear. You don't even have to write copy constructor, destructor or assignment operator any more. They all just work. Your assignment operator is wrong because it breaks on self-assignment. It also copies the object three times instead of once and doesn't return a reference.

Comment: `coef=new int[grad];` is grad a valid number here?

Comment: The `Polinom(int x, int * c)` constructor  doesn't initialize `grad`. The default constructor, if used, will cause the destructor to invoke UB by using `delete[]` on a pointer allocated by plain non-array `new`.

Comment: @NeilKirk It doesn't break on self-assignment. OTOH, it is needlessly inefficient - a copy-and-swap without the swap.

Comment: @T.C. It deletes coef and then reads from the other's coef. The data is lost.

Comment: @NeilKirk It takes the argument by value, so deleting coef will never affect the later reading.

Comment: @MustafaOzturk that was the problem!! It seems that I forgot to define grad in the constructor. Thank you so much.

Comment: @T.C. Aha you are correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor

```
Polinom::Polinom(int x, int * c)
{
  int i;
  coef=new int[x];
  for(i=0;i<x;i++)
  {
    coef[i]=c[i];
  }
}
```

You forgot to update the value of grad to x. that causes Q.grad in your = operator to contain garbage and fails.

Here is the changed code

```
Polinom::Polinom(int x, int * c)
{
  int i;
  grad = x;
  coef=new int[x];
  for(i=0;i<x;i++)
  {
    coef[i]=c[i];
  }
}
```